# What a "linear modifier" does on the sequencer?

Tags: modifiers, video-sequence-editor, video

When on the sequencer, there's this "Use Linear Modifiers" option.. What does It mean?

by the guide: *"Calculate modifiers in linear space instead of sequencer space."*

but which is the "sequencer space"? How does It differ?

[image: linear_modifiers_option]

Comment: I can't confirm this, because I haven't found it documented any better than you have, nor have I looked at the source code, but I assume it's about the colour managent. Take a look at [Color Management](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/post_process/color_management.html) in the online manual, to get an idea of how it' done in Blender.